# How to wrap controllers with a mongoDB session object, in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Id like to structurally add a session object inside every controller, as most of my services used in controllers require a mongodb "session" object, to do any DB updates. This is a node.js project written with express.js + typescript

I have a function that I call in almost every controller, it's something like

```
runInTransaction<T>(mutations: CallBackFunc<T>, options : any) {
     const session = await mongoose.startSession();
     session.startTransaction(options);
  
     try{
         const value = await mutation(session);
         await session.commitTransaction();
         return value;
     }
      catch(e) {
          await session.abortTransaction();
          throw e;
    }
    finally {
           session.endSession();
     }
}
```

then, the controller looks something like:

```
requestHandler(req, res, next) {
   const { params } = req.body;

   const response = runInTransaction(async session => {
     const someData = await someService.getData(params, session);
      return await someOtherService.updateData(someData, session);
   });

   return res.status(200).json(respnse);
}
```

The problem is that I am doing this in every single one of the controllers. How can I structurally do something like this in a neater way ? from a architecture perspective.

Id really appreciate your insight

Answer (score 0):

It's not a session, but a client connection. Yes, you want to export that connection for other modules to use. You want to utilize the `app.locals` like `app.locals.client = client;` then in your other modules you do like:

```
const app = express();

async function index (req, res) {
  let db = req.app.locals.client.db("my-db");
```